# How to restore the main kernel from the rescue kernel in Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, grub, rescue

I have a Fedora 37 installation which kernel was corrupted when trying to setup propietary nvidia graphics. I lost wifi and all control to the screen. Booting into the rescue option in Grub fixes it and things work as expected. How can I use that rescue to repair or replace the main kernel in order to boot from the standard 1st grub option?